# How to extract the exact match from the string by using REGEXEXTRACT in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have one issue with REGEXEXTRACT in Google Sheet. I want to match and extract the exact word. If I use the below formula, it will display the result “Sing,” but I want it to display “NA.” Because the source cell i.e A1 cell does not have the “Sing” word but it has the word "Singapore".
=regexextract(A1,”(?i)Sing”)
So, how can we extract the exact match instead of the partial match?
Thanks & Regards,
Vineet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

REGEXEXTRACT is going to extract the part of the string that matches your regex expression. What you need to use is REGEXMATCH which returns a TRUE or FALSE and use it as a condition for IF:

```
=IF(REGEXMATCH(A1,(?i)Sing”), A1,"")
```

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=IF(REGEXMATCH(A1; "\b(?i)sing\b"); A1; "NA")
```

[image]

```
(?i)    case insensitive
\b      boundary
```